# what is the right way to include a variable in an sql statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to include a variable in my sql statement but it's not outputting any data.
How do I include a variable correctly?

`$vStyles = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT slug from vf_venuestyles WHERE vid = "$vid"');`

Comment: The right way is to use parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the quote marks around:
`$vStyles = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT slug from vf_venuestyles WHERE vid = '$vid'");`

But, unless that function / class already does something magic about that, you should look into using something with proper prepared statements.

Comment: The function is part of WordPress.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie - this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use prepared statement

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);

// insert line
$name = 'one';
$value = 1;
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: he's apparently using WordPress, I don't think it uses PDO. Is there a WP way to do prepared queries?

Answer (score 0):

Variables only get executed if they are inside **double** quotes.

Simply swap your quotation marks like this:

```
$vStyles = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT slug from vf_venuestyles WHERE vid = '$vid'");
```

Or **combine** the query with the variable, like this, remembering to also include the secondary quotation marks:

```
$vStyles = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT slug from vf_venuestyles WHERE vid = '" . $vid . '"');
```

Hope this helps! :)